# best way of generating tab in the middle of the screen

Tags: android

> What i really want is dividing the screen into two half vertically.The
>   top screen contain an activity that perform some certain task.The
>   another bottom screen contain the Tab Activity that can be swiped.
>
> How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use weight. Suppose:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/belowLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how can i add tabs in belowlayout?

Comment: You can just use TabLayout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html